# this keyword in arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

```
var cat = {
lives: 9,
jumps: () => {
console.log(this.lives)
 }
}
```

I have heard that 'this' keyword in arrow function will point to the parent scope, so I have tried putting a variable with lives=9 in global object in  node and this doesn't seems to work, am I missing something?

```
var lives=9
var cat = {
lives: 9,
jumps: () => {
console.log(this.lives)
 }
}
```

Comment: Your second piece of code should work *as long as* it's in the global scope. Otherwise variables will not be attached to `this`. In global scope `this` will be the global object.

Comment: Define `this doesn't seems to work`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions have a lexical `this` which means that the value of `this` inside the function is the same as the value of `this` outside the function.

It does not mean that `this` points to an object containing all the variables from outside the function.

```js
const anObject = {
  aValue: "example value",
  aMethod: function() {
    console.log("aMethod", this.aValue);

    const arrow = () => {
      console.log("arrow", this.aValue);
    }
    
    arrow();
  }
}

anObject.aMethod();

const copyOfAMethod = anObject.aMethod;
copyOfAMethod();
```

Because `aMethod` is called as a method on `anObject`, the value of `this` inside `aMethod` is `anObject`.

Because `arrow` is declared inside `aMethod`, the value of `this` is the same as it is for `aMethod`.

If the function is copied elsewhere so it has a different `this` value, then the arrow function created when the copy is called it will have the same different value.

Comment: so the  'this ' of cat object is undefined?

Comment: @RahulRNair — No. It will be whatever the value of `this` is outside the object. Your code doesn't show enough context to determine what that will be.

Comment: thanks man,i got the idea,i was confused with the parent scoping of arrow function,the code makes sense now, thanks!